# pointer & iterator c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I must do a project.
I have a sparse matrix, with 3 array:

1. val
2. pr for rows position
3. pc for columns position

Now i've a problem with the iterator. 
I must return a pointer to struct that contain 3 thing:

1. value
2. row
3. columns

```
class const_iterator; // forward declaration

class iterator {
    friend class const_iterator;  
    friend class sparsematrix;

public:

    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
typedef T value_type;
typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef T* pointer;
typedef T& reference;

    iterator() : ptr(0) {}

    iterator(const iterator &other) : ptr(other.ptr) {}

    iterator& operator=(const iterator &other) {
        ptr = other.ptr;
        return *this;
    }
    ~iterator() {}
       /**
    * Operatore di dereferenziamento.
    * @return il dato "puntato" dall'iteratore.
    */
    reference operator*() const {
        return *ptr;
    }
       /**
    * Operatore freccia. 
    * 
    * @return il puntatore al dato "puntato" dall'iteratore.
    */
    pointer operator->() const {
        return ptr;
    }
           /**
    * Operatore di confronto (uguaglianza). 
    * 
    * @param other iteratore da confrontare
    * @return true se i due iteratori "puntano" allo stesso dato
    */
    bool operator==(const iterator &other) const {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di confronto (disuguaglianza). 
    * 
    * @param other iteratore da confrontare
    * @return true se i due iteratori "puntano" a dati diversi
    */
    bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di confronto (uguaglianza). 
    * 
    * @param other const_iteratore da confrontare
    * @return true se i due iteratori "puntano" allo stesso dato
    */
    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return ptr == other.ptr; // vedi const_iterator
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di confronto (uguaglianza). 
    * 
    * @param other const_iteratore da confrontare
    * @return true se i due iteratori "puntano" a dati diversi
    */
    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di "elemento successivo". Versione pre-incremento. 
    * 
    * @return l'iteratore che "punta" all'elemento successivo
    */
    iterator &operator++() {
        ++ptr;
        return *this;
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di "elemento successivo". Versione post-incremento. 
    * 
    * @return l'iteratore che "punta" all'elemento successivo
    */
    iterator operator++(int) {
        iterator tmp(ptr);
        ++ptr;
        return tmp;
    }
private:
    value_type *ptr;
       /**
    * Costruttore di inizializzazione.
    * @param p puntatore ai dati
    */
    explicit iterator(value_type *p) : ptr(p){}
}; // iterator
    /**
    * Inizio Const Iterator
    */
class const_iterator {
    friend class iterator;  
    friend class sparsematrix;

public:
           typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
       typedef T value_type;
       typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
       typedef const T* pointer;
       typedef const T& reference;

    const_iterator() : ptr(0) {}

    const_iterator(const const_iterator &other) : ptr(other.ptr) {}

    const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator &other) {
        ptr = other.ptr;
        return *this;
    }
    ~const_iterator() {}
       /**
    * Costruttore di conversione.
    * @param other iterator da convertire
    */
    const_iterator(const iterator &other) : ptr(other.ptr) {}
       /**
    * Operatore di dereferenziamento.
    * @return il dato "puntato" dall'iteratore.
    */
    reference operator*() const {
        return *ptr;
    }
       /**
    * Operatore freccia.
    * @return il puntatore al dato "puntato" dall'iteratore.
    */
    pointer operator->() const {
        return ptr;
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di confronto (uguaglianza).
    * @param other const_iteratore da confrontare
    * @return true se i due iteratori "puntano" allo stesso dato
    */
    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di confronto (disuguaglianza).
    * @param other const_iteratore da confrontare
    * @return true se i due iteratori "puntano" a dati diversi
    */
    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
       /**
    * Operatore di "elemento successivo". Versione pre-incremento.
    * @return l'iteratore che "punta" all'elemento successivo
    */
    const_iterator &operator++() {
        ++ptr;
        return *this;
    }
           /**
    * Operatore di "elemento successivo". Versione post-incremento.
    * @return l'iteratore che "punta" all'elemento successivo
    */
    const_iterator operator++(int) {
        const_iterator tmp(ptr);
        ++ptr;
        return tmp;
    }
private:
    const T *ptr;
       /**
    * Costruttore di inizializzazione.
    * @param p puntatore ai dati
    */
    explicit const_iterator(const T *p) : ptr(p)  {}
}; // const_iterator

iterator begin() {
    return iterator(val);
}

iterator end() {
    return iterator(val + size);
}

const_iterator begin() const {
    return const_iterator(val);
}

const_iterator end() const {
    return const_iterator(val + size);
}
```

How must to do for return a struct?
Sorry for my horrible english!

Comment: Do you understand what the meaning of "T" is in that code you copy-pasted? Do you understand why operator* returns "reference" instead of "value_type"?

Comment: Nope T is only type name.
I don't understand...

Comment: Posting the definition of `sparsematrix` might help (is it a class? a templated class?); also removing irrelevant code might help too (your `const_iterator` doesn't help); please also add your attempt at fixing the problem ("return a struct") - code might explain better than english what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can return structs from functions explicitly in C(++). I can't easily follow your example (sorry!), but you just define their return type as your struct. For example:

```
typedef struct  { 
       int a, b, c;
} MY_STRUCT_TYPE;

MY_STRUCT_TYPE returnStruct(MY_STRUCT_TYPE example) {
   MY_STRUCT_TYPE returnValues;
   returnValues.a=example.a*2;
   returnValues.b=example.b*2;
   returnValues.c=example.c*2;

   return(returnValues);
}    

int main()
{
struct MY_STRUCT_TYPE example; 
example.a=5; example.b=10; example.c=15;  
example=returnStruct(example);
//a=10; b=20; c=30
}
```

Comment: `MY_STRUCT_TYPE` is not a type in your example. You either have to add `typedef` before `struct` or put `MY_STRUCT_TYPE` right after `struct` keyword.

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right. And yes, something like that user2747630.